# Android PayPal Daylight saving time

Tags: android, time, paypal, save, dst

I have the paypal sdk working perfect in android application using android studio. But the response from a transaction is giving me the time one hour behind the correct time. Here is the logcat where its outputting the wrong time:

```
{
  "response": {
    "state": "approved",
    "id": "PAY-***********",
    "create_time": "2015-04-29T11:17:42Z",
    "intent": "sale"
  },
  "client": {
    "platform": "Android",
    "paypal_sdk_version": "2.0.2",
    "product_name": "PayPal-Android-SDK",
    "environment": "sandbox"
  },
  "response_type": "payment"
}
```

Any ideas how i could correct this?

Comment: What is your definition of "correct time"? The trailing "Z" in the timestamp indicates it is in 'Zulu' time, or GMT/UTC, which is generally what you want and how you should parse it. UTC does [*not* observe daylight saving](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time#Daylight_saving_time), as it's the constant frame of reference other time zones are expressed relative to. If you find the time is off, you're probably making the mistake of using the device's locale as point of reference.

Comment: sorry, correct  time to me should be one hour ahead of the time it is currently outputting. oh right interesting thanks!  How would I go about changing this in order to show +1 hour ahead?

Comment: First, parse the timestamp (i.e. using `SimpleDateFormat`) with a UTC timezone. This should give you a `Date`. Then display that date using another `DateFormat` (i.e. use the functionality provided by ` android.text.format.DateFormat`) initialised with the user's locale/timezone.